# error in Python while using win32com

Tags: python, win32com

I am getting an error while using win32com in python:what is the problem ?

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "Correct_sentence.py", line 12, in <module>
  File "pyttsx\__init__.pyc", line 39, in init
  File "pyttsx\engine.pyc", line 45, in __init__
  File "pyttsx\driver.pyc", line 66, in __init__
  File "pyttsx\drivers\sapi5.pyc", line 37, in buildDriver
  File "pyttsx\drivers\sapi5.pyc", line 56, in __init__
  File "pyttsx\drivers\sapi5.pyc", line 98, in setProperty
  File "win32com\client\dynamic.pyc", line 549, in __setattr__
pywintypes.com_error: (-2147352573, '\xd5\xd2\xb2\xbb\xb5\xbd\xb3\xc9\xd4\xb1\xa1\xa3', None, None)
```

Comment: Please provide your code too.

Comment: can you share some more information about what you have written in your line12 of Correct_sentence.py

Comment: line 12 is "engine=pyttsx.init()",I use pyttsx moduel to turn text into speech.and my code in pycharm is correct,but i use py2exe make Correct_sentence.py into exe,while run Correct_sentence.exe occured error.what is the problem

Comment: And if i delete the code about pyttsx,the exe can run correctly